# How to test if an object is a django UploadedFile?

Tags: python, django

I am using django3.1 and python 3.7.

I have a dictionary as follow:

```
{'text2': 'text2', 'file2': <UploadedFile: img5.jpg (image/jpeg)>, 'file22': <UploadedFile: img8.jpg (image/jpeg)>}
```

I want to print out the image names:

```
img5.jpg
img8.jpg
```

When I check type of `<UploadedFile: img5.jpg (image/jpeg)>`, it says:

```
<class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile'>
```

I tried following:

```
data1 = {'text2': 'text2', 'file2': <UploadedFile: img5.jpg (image/jpeg)>, 'file22': <UploadedFile: img8.jpg (image/jpeg)>}

for key in data1:

    if isinstance(data1[key], io.IOBase):
        print(data1[key].name)
    else: 
        print('not a file')
```

It always shows `not a file`.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: why are you checking io.IOBase class instead of UploadedFile also why don't you just look into request.Files instead

Comment: in this case, i have no access to request.Files. I did not know how to get UploadedFile type:))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`UploadedFile`**--(doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile) class to check the conditions

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import UploadedFile

data = {}  # you data

for key, value in data.items():
    if isinstance(value, UploadedFile):
        print(value.name)
```